# Debug assertion failed error in vector

Tags: c++, debugging, vector

I am writing some functions that use a third party open source library. In release mode, it randomly crashes with `The programme has stopped working`, but no other info. So, i am trying to debug this issue.

When i run in Debug mode, i get the:

`vector <bool> iterator not dereferencable` error, and it Breaks to

```
const _Vbase *_Getptr() const
        {   // get pointer to base word
 #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
        if (this->_Getcont() == 0
            || this->_Myptr == 0
            || 0 <= this->_Valid(0))
            {   // report error
            _DEBUG_ERROR("vector<bool> iterator not dereferencable");
            _SCL_SECURE_OUT_OF_RANGE;
            }
```

in

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\vector`

I know there is info about this on here, searching tells me that most likely it is an issue with populating too many elements into the vector.

**My question is:**

As the breakpoint occurs in `vector`, and not in my code, or the third party code, how can i find which specific function is causing this error?

(the third party library is littered with both `vector<bool>` and `iterator`.

Thank you.

Comment: How to debug 101: call stack

Comment: Ah I see. The current line in the call stack just shows: > msvcp140d.dll!00007ffd173f0806() Unknown. And when i click it, gives `pdb not loaded.

Comment: Looks like the 3rd-party library is buggy and cannot be used.

Comment: @anti Follow the call stack until you find your own code. That's where you need to start looking.

Comment: i am embarrassed to say that I did not know about the call stack. I am kinda new to programming, as you can no doubt tell. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Haha I don't know when I first discovered the call stack, certainly not the first day I started programming. It was enlightening...

Answer (score 1):

Your debugger has a feature named "call stack". It shows a stack of all functions in the order they called each other.

When a crash happens, you are at the top of that call stack. Now it's just a matter of looking downwards the call stack until you find your own code. Double-click the function and IDE points you to the code location.

In Visual Studio: Menu Debug > Windows > Call Stack (Ctrl+Alt+C).

Comment: Thank you! My stack has five lines, the top one being msvcp140d.dll!00007ffd173f0806() Unknown. And when i click it, gives `pdb not loaded. So I should be looking in the lines underneath to see what is causing this? (I will also get myself schooled up about the call stack) thanks again

Comment: Right-click on the msvcp... line and choose "load symbols", this will download the PDB from MS symbol server. You may have to enable symbol server under Options > Debug first.